# Perl multi dimensional hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I have a config file with and below is one of the section it contains:

```
[EXCLUDE_LIST]
c1=A
c2=B|C
c3=A
c1=B
```

I have a perl script and it contains a sub which reads the above section from config and checks whether a particular group (cX) is present in the config. Input parameters for this sub is a hash that is tied (using tie) to the config file. When I was debugging the code, I tried to display all the contents of EXCLUDE_LIST section, the program printed some junk ARRAY[memory_address] while displaying c1 value(s). this is because there is duplicate entry for c1.

My Question: How do I include a validation logic in the above sub to exit the process if there are any duplicate entries.

this is how the config section entries are accessed in my script:

```
$cfg->{EXCLUDE_LIST}->{cX}
```

TIA.

Comment: Please show the whole `sub`. I don't think program printed junk values because of duplicate entry of `c1`

Comment: Are you using a CPAN module to processv your config file?

Comment: Yes Borodin, I am using Config::IniFiles module.

Answer (score 1):

It would help enormously if you had told us which module you had used to read your config file, or if it is custom software (a bad idea as there are very many config file modules already out there) then you should show us the code. Without that information this answer has to be an (informed) guess

I suspect that whatever you are using to read your config file handles duplicate entries by storing an *array* of all the different values for a given key. In your case, the value of `$cfg->{EXCLUDE_LIST}{c1}` would be `['A', 'B']`

You can handle this by checking whether the hash value is a *reference*, like this

```
while ( my ($key, $val) = each %{ $cfg->{EXCLUDE_LIST} } ) {

    if ( ref $val ) {
        print "$key=", join(',', @$val), "\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$key=$val\n";
    }
}
```

> My Question: How do I include a validation logic in the above sub to exit the process if there are any duplicate entries.

You can do a similar test, but `die` if the value is a reference

```
die qq{Multiple occurrences of "$key"} if ref $val;
```

Comment: thanks Borodin. this is exactly what I have implemented at work today and it worked :) thanks for taking time and replying.